# Is it possible to make a view ignore all touches while a UITouchDragExit control event is being performed on one of its subviews?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicontrolevents

I have a `UIView` with a bunch of subviews. Each subview can either be clicked (`UITouchUpInside`) or 'swiped' (`UITouchDragExit`) to perform a different action. Both actions work as intended separately, but since the subviews are really close together, the `UITouchDragExit` Control event of one view accidentally activates the `UITouchUpInside` of the subview above it.

In order to avoid this, I was thinking of making the subview ignore all other touches to its other subviews until the `UITouchDragExit` gesture is over. What would be the best way of accomplishing this? In other words how can I detect the start/end of UITouchDragExit?

Thanks in advance!